# IPC in Mono & .NET

Tags: c#, .net, mono, ipc, config

I am implementing a configuartion mechanism (GUI) for my windows service which is to be portable (linux daemon) via mono. I am using the app.config file and planned to expose methods used to write to it using WCF and named pipes. However, Now I have learned that named pipes are not implemented in Mono yet. HTTP endpoints are however, and I was wondering if I could use HTTPbinding for local IPC, to allow my GUI to modify the config file of the service. I that impossible/bad practice?

If this is a bad idea, what are the alternatives? If all im doing is configuration, is IPC overkill? Is editing an external file or database a better alternavtive (values would not be changed so often) however, i have values that would not seem to 'fit' in a DB, like single ints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems fine, however I would rather use plain unix sockets. In fact, they are often used instead of named pipes. And I used them with mono, simply worked.

Comment: thanks, this seems like a good solution, however I have now been encouraged to use a simple editable external file to make things a little more robust.